# Problems with generating grid and images for map with Canvas HTML

Tags: javascript, dictionary, canvas

I'm doing a map with canvas for my future browser game. But, I have a some problems with the tiles and grid generation. Actually, I have three steps in my algorithm: I first generate the background tiles (grass, sea, ...) with a loop of drawImage, then I generate the top layer tiles (villages, oasis, ...) with a loop of drawImage again and to finish I generate the grid with a loop of moveTo/lineTo.

To illustrate you all of this, I will show you my algorithm:

```js
redrawMapContent: function() {
    this.ctx = document.getElementById(this.id).getContext("2d");

    this.drawTilesMap(0, this.ctx);
    this.drawTilesMap(1, this.ctx);
    this.drawGridMap(this.ctx);
    camera.recenterOnMyCity();
},

drawTilesMap: function(layer, ctx) {
    var tileSize = map.getTileSize();
    var startCol = Math.floor(camera.x / tileSize);
    var startRow = Math.floor(camera.y / tileSize);
     

    var endCol; var endRow;
    if (camera.width > tileSize * map.cols) endCol = startCol + map.cols - 1;
    else  endCol = startCol + (camera.width / tileSize);

    if (camera.height > tileSize * map.rows) endRow = startCol + map.rows - 1;
    else  endRow = startRow + (camera.height / tileSize);
   
     
    var offsetX = -camera.x + startCol * tileSize;
    var offsetY = -camera.y + startRow * tileSize;
      
    var imageTilesAtlas = new Image();
    imageTilesAtlas.onload = function() {
     for (var c = startCol; c <= endCol; c++) {
      for (var r = startRow; r <= endRow; r++) {
           var tile = map.getTile(layer, c, r); 
           var x = (c - startCol) * tileSize + offsetX;
           var y = (r - startRow) * tileSize + offsetY;
           if (tile !== 0) { // 0 => empty tile
              ctx.drawImage(
                imageTilesAtlas,
                (tile - 1) * map.defaultTileSize, 
                0, 
                map.defaultTileSize, 
                map.defaultTileSize, 
                Math.round(x),  
                Math.round(y), 
                tileSize, 
                tileSize 
              );
           }
      }
     }
    };
    imageTilesAtlas.src = this.tileAtlas;
},

drawGridMap: function (ctx) {
    var tileSize = map.getTileSize();
    var width = map.cols * tileSize;
    var height = map.rows * tileSize;
    var x, y;

    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(100,100,100,0.3)";

    for (var r = 0; r < map.rows; r++) {
     x = - camera.x;
     y = r * tileSize - camera.y;
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(x, y);
     ctx.lineTo(width, y);
     ctx.stroke();
    }
    for (var c = 0; c < map.cols; c++) {
     x = c * tileSize - camera.x;
     y = - camera.y;
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(x, y);
     ctx.lineTo(x, height);
     ctx.stroke();
    }
},
```

The problem is that sometimes there is only the background tiles which are generated. Moreover, the grid is never generated.
I don't know how to resolve this, I have no error in the console and I don't anything wrong.

Thank you for your answers (and sorry for my English, I'm french and it's the first time I post on English forum).

Answer (score 0):

I have had many problems loading images until i used this pattern:

```
function loadImage(src, callback) {
    img = document.createElement('img');
    img.addEventListener('load', function() { callback(img); } , false);
    img.src = src;
}

function run(sprites) {
    tileAtlas = [];
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    var counter = 0;
    for (var y = 0; y < 10; y++){
         for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
              tileAtlas[counter] = ctx.getImageData(
                                   x * tileSize, 
                                   y * tileSize, 
                                   x * tileSize + tileSize, 
                                   y * tileSize + tileSize);
              counter++;
         }
     }


    init();
    loop();

}

loadImage("sprites.png", run);
```

I got it here:
http://codeincomplete.com/posts/javascript-game-foundations-loading-assets/
I had tried the method you are using and it didn't quite work properly. This method gives time for loading the image.

As far as your grid, i looked at it in JSBIN and it seems to work as long as i substituted dummy values for camera.x and tileSize. Maybe there is a problem with the camera? Loading all of your tiles into a TilesAtlas array of image objects might be a better way to go, each image can have an id corresponding to the index of TileAtlas. This way you only load it once.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I think that I've solved my tiles generation problem with your loadImage() method : thank you for this. Now, i've :

```js
loadImage: function (src, ctx) {
     img = document.createElement('img');
     img.addEventListener('load', function() { 
      canvas.drawTilesMap(0, ctx, img); // je génère les tiles en background layer de la map
   canvas.drawTilesMap(1, ctx, img); // je génère les tiles en top layer de la map
     } , false);
     img.src = src;
 },

drawMapContent: function() {
  this.ctx = document.getElementById(this.id).getContext("2d");
  camera.constructCamera(this.width, this.height);

  this.loadImage(this.tileAtlas, this.ctx);
  this.drawGridMap(this.ctx, camera.x, camera.y); // je génère la grille de la map
  
  camera.recenterOnMyCity();
 },


 drawTilesMap: function(layer, ctx) {
  var tileSize = map.getTileSize();
  var startCol = Math.floor(camera.x / tileSize);
     var startRow = Math.floor(camera.y / tileSize);
     
     /*********** On empêche l'algo de créer des cases juste pour combler la vue caméra ***********/
     var endCol; var endRow;
     if (camera.width > tileSize * map.cols) endCol = startCol + map.cols - 1;
     else  endCol = startCol + (camera.width / tileSize);

     if (camera.height > tileSize * map.rows) endRow = startCol + map.rows - 1;
     else  endRow = startRow + (camera.height / tileSize);
     /*********************************************************************************************/
     
     var offsetX = -camera.x + startCol * tileSize;
     var offsetY = -camera.y + startRow * tileSize;

     for (var c = startCol; c <= endCol; c++) {
         for (var r = startRow; r <= endRow; r++) {
             var tile = map.getTile(layer, c, r); // recupère le type de case (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ou 6)
             var x = (c - startCol) * tileSize + offsetX;
             var y = (r - startRow) * tileSize + offsetY;
             if (tile !== 0) { // 0 => empty tile
                 ctx.drawImage(
                     img, // image contenant les tiles
                     (tile - 1) * map.defaultTileSize, // x à partir duquel prendre l'image (pour sélectionner la bonne texture)
                     0, // y à partir duquel prendre l'image (pour sélectionner la bonne texture)
                     map.defaultTileSize, // source width
                     map.defaultTileSize, // source height
                     Math.round(x),  // target x
                     Math.round(y), // target y
                     tileSize, // target width
                     tileSize // target height
                 );
             }
         }
     }
 },

 drawGridMap: function (ctx, cameraX, cameraY) {
  var tileSize = map.getTileSize();
     var width = map.cols * tileSize;
     var height = map.rows * tileSize;
     var x, y;

     ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(100,100,100,0.3)"; // couleur et opacité du quadrillage

     for (var r = 0; r < map.rows; r++) {
         x = - cameraX;
         y = r * tileSize - cameraY;
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(x, y);
         ctx.lineTo(width, y);
         ctx.stroke();
     }
     for (var c = 0; c < map.cols; c++) {
         x = c * tileSize - cameraX;
         y = - cameraY;
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(x, y);
         ctx.lineTo(x, height);
         ctx.stroke();
     }
 },
```

I didn't really understand when you say to load tiles in tilesAtlas : when all the tiles are in this array how can you draw the differents tiles ? Browse this array and drawImage() on all the index ? And when you say that this method will load images once, I think that if you move on the map, you'll have to change the content of this array don't you ?

But for the grid, it's so weird, I spy the aglorithme and there is no problem : it does lines from one part of the canvas to the other side of the canvas. What values of camera.x and tileSize did you took ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps tilesAtlas is confusing. My idea is to create an array of images, lets call it Tiles.

> Tiles[0] is an image of the sand tile. Tiles[1] is an image of the
>   grass tile. etc.

You could even have a Tile class containing Tile properties. Then in the map of the world, you have tile data somewhere.

> World[0][0] = 0. World[0][1] = 1.

0 denotes sand tile. 
1 denotes grass tile.

Comment: Ok thank you and for the grid do you have any idea ?